# How to have different elements with same name but different type in XSD v1.0

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xsd-1.0

I've a codebase that is relatively large that incorporates 2 types of XML:

```
<tag ref="var_ref" />
```

or

```
<tag>value</tag>
```

However, I want the following to fail to validate because it is in our case ambiguous.

```
<tag ref="var_ref">value</tag>
```

I see that alternatives are possible in v1.1, but does anyone have a hack for XSD 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest hack for 1.0 is to give distinct names to these two distinct validation behaviors.  (Some authorities would say that this is not a hack but just simpler design.  Why give the same name to two things which are so obviously different in structure?  Call things what they are:  when they are different, call them different things.  It makes many things simpler, including XML and XML processing.)

If your target namespace is bound to prefix `tns`, you might write:

```
<xsd:element name="tns:TAG" abstract="true"/>
<xsd:element name="tag" type="xsd:string" 
             substitutionGroup="tns:TAG"/>
<xsd:element name="tagref" 
             substitutionGroup="tns:TAG">
  <xsd:sequence/>
  <xsd:attribute name="ref" type="xsd:IDREF"/>
  <!--* or adjust the type to suit ... *-->
</xsd:element>
```

Then replace all references to `tns:tag` in your existing content models with references to `tns:TAG`.

Comment: The biggest reason is that we have a large set of xml files that have not to this point been validated. We'd like to validate them using our new schemas.

Agreed that the 'two things' are different in structure, but the use is not. They are interpreted similarly - in the first case, it is a variable reference; in the other, a direct string value.